# Fractal Tree - branches not drawn

Tags: c++, graphics, iteration, sfml, fractals

Currently, I'm trying to draw a symmetric binary tree through IFS (Iterated Function Systems):

[image]

but the result is always only the branch tips:

[image].

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong or what I'm missing.

This is the IFS:

[image: here]

This is my code:

```
RenderWindow window(VideoMode(480, 640), "fractals everywhere");
CircleShape point(1);
int chance;
float x, y, w, h, nx, ny, px, py;

void SymmetricBinaryTrees()
{
    float r = 0.57f;
    float o = 0.785f;

    chance = rand() % 3;

    switch (chance)
    {
    case 0:
        nx = r * cos(o) * x + (-1 * r * sin(o) * y);
        ny = r * sin(o) * x + r * cos(o) * y + 1;
        break;
    case 1:
        nx = r * cos(o) * x + r * sin(o) * y;
        ny = -1 * r * sin(o) * x + r * cos(o) * y + 1;
        break;
    case 2:
        nx = x;
        ny = y;
        break;
    }
}

void nextPoint()
{
    SymmetricBinaryTrees();

    x = nx; y = ny;
}

void drawPoint()
{
    px = _map(x, -1.078, 1.078f, 0, w); py = _map(y, 0.f, 2.078f, h, 0); // maps the position accordingly
    point.setPosition(px, py);

    window.draw(point);
}

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    w = window.getSize().x * 1.f;
    h = window.getSize().y * 1.f;

    x = 0.f; y = 0.f;

    window.setFramerateLimit(60);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        Event e;

        while (window.pollEvent(e))
            if (e.type == Event::Closed) window.close();

        for (int i = 1; i <= 500; i++)
        {
            drawPoint();
            nextPoint();
        }

        window.display();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[This](http://ecademy.agnesscott.edu/~lriddle/ifs/pythagorean/symbinarytree.htm) is the website that I'm using for my code.

If anyone could help me or has any idea I'd be very grateful, thank you.

Comment: Shouldn't the code draw a line from `x, y` to `nx, ny`?

Answer (score 4):

I share @beyond opinion, I think you're complicating things too much. It will be easier with a different approach. Let's make things easier.

With a recursive function, we can easily understand what should be done each step.
Consider we start from a **initial point**, then trace a **line** on an **angle** of a given **lenght**, so we need a function like:

```
void createTreeRecursive(sf::VertexArray &tree, sf::Vector2f point, float angle, float lenght)
```

Where `tree` will be our line set, which compose the tree itself.

First thing we can do, is to set the first point, which is already known:

```
// Add first point
tree.append(sf::Vertex(point, treeColor));
```

Now we need to calculate our next point, to form a line. With simple trigonometric functions we can determine that point:

```
float newX = point.x + (cos((2.f * PI / 360.f) * angle) * lenght);
float newY = point.y - (sin((2.f * PI / 360.f) * angle) * lenght);  // Caution here! Minus(-) sign because we're drawing upwards
```

So we add this second point, and then split the tree into 2 new branches, each one rotated some certain degrees:

```
// Add second point
tree.append(sf::Vertex(nextPoint, treeColor));

// Create sub-tree from 2nd point, rotating +45 degrees (i.e. counterclockwise), reducing lenght of the new branch by 0.6 factor
createTreeRecursive(tree, nextPoint, angle + O, lenght * R);

// Same with the other sub-tree, but rotating -45 (i.e. clockwise)
createTreeRecursive(tree, nextPoint, angle - O, lenght * R);
```

We need a base case for our recursive function, in this case, I choose 3 as minimum lenght:

```
if (lenght < 3)
    // End condition, can be modified
    return;
```

this must be out first check.

So we're done, we only need the initial call:

```
sf::VertexArray createTree(){
    // Our tree will be made out of lines
    sf::VertexArray ret(sf::PrimitiveType::Lines);
    // Initial point at botton-center(250, 450), with a 90 degrees rotation, first branch lenght 200 
    createTreeRecursive(ret, sf::Vector2f(250, 450), 90, 200);
    return ret;
}
```

And the result is:

[image]

### Full code

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

const double PI = 3.141592;
const double R = 0.57;  // Reduction factor
const double O = 45;    // Degree rotation each time
sf::Color treeColor = sf::Color::Blue;

void createTreeRecursive(sf::VertexArray &tree, sf::Vector2f point, float angle, float lenght){
    if (lenght < 3)
        // End condition, can be modified
        return;

    // Add first point
    tree.append(sf::Vertex(point, treeColor));
    float newX = point.x + (cos((2.f * PI / 360.f) * angle) * lenght);
    float newY = point.y - (sin((2.f * PI / 360.f) * angle) * lenght);  // Caution here! Minus(-) sign because we're drawing upwards
    sf::Vector2f nextPoint(newX, newY);
    // Add second point
    tree.append(sf::Vertex(nextPoint, treeColor));

    // Create sub-tree from 2nd point, rotating +45 degrees (i.e. counterclockwise), reducing lenght of the new branch by 0.6 factor
    createTreeRecursive(tree, nextPoint, angle + O, lenght * R);

    // Same with the other sub-tree, but rotating -45 (i.e. clockwise)
    createTreeRecursive(tree, nextPoint, angle - O, lenght * R);
}

sf::VertexArray createTree(){
    // Our tree will be made out of lines
    sf::VertexArray ret(sf::PrimitiveType::Lines);
    // Initial point at bottom-center(250, 450), with a 90 degrees rotation, first branch lenght 200 
    createTreeRecursive(ret, sf::Vector2f(250, 450), 90, 200);
    return ret;
}

int main()
{
    RenderWindow window({ 500, 500 }, "SFML Tree", Style::Close);

    auto tree = createTree();

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        for (Event event; window.pollEvent(event);){
            if (event.type == Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear();
        window.draw(tree);
        window.display();
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would advice you to use recursion with a function that 1) draws the current branch (as a line), and then 2) creates two new branches from the current branch. Using global variables doesn't help you either. Looks like you should rethink your approach.

Answer (score 0):

For Linux is:

```cpp
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <cmath>

const double PI = 3.141592;
const double R = 0.57;
const double O = 45;
sf::Color treeColor = sf::Color::Blue;

void createTreeRecursive(sf::VertexArray &tree, sf::Vector2f point, float angle, float lenght){
    if (lenght < 3)

        return;


    tree.append(sf::Vertex(point, treeColor));
    float newX = point.x + (cos((2.f * PI / 360.f) * angle) * lenght);
    float newY = point.y - (sin((2.f * PI / 360.f) * angle) * lenght);
    sf::Vector2f nextPoint(newX, newY);

    tree.append(sf::Vertex(nextPoint, treeColor));


    createTreeRecursive(tree, nextPoint, angle + O, lenght * R);


    createTreeRecursive(tree, nextPoint, angle - O, lenght * R);
}

sf::VertexArray createTree(){

    sf::VertexArray ret(sf::PrimitiveType::Lines);

    createTreeRecursive(ret, sf::Vector2f(250, 450), 90, 200);
    return ret;
}

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window({ 500, 500 }, "SFML Tree", sf::Style::Close);

    auto tree = createTree();

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        for (sf::Event event; window.pollEvent(event);){
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear();
        window.draw(tree);
        window.display();
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```